# C program asking for user input multiple times

Tags: c, shared-memory

Writing a very basic C program that demonstrates shared memory. The program needs to keep calculating the sum of two inputs until the user does a `^C` (not shown here).

What I have so far is that my parent captures user input, then tells the child to calculate the sum, which the parent then prints the sum (as the assignment suggests).

Attached is my code.

```
// Fork the process                                                   
while(1) {                                                            
    // Declare a shared memory integer array                          
    int *shared_ints = mmap(NULL, shared_seg_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);                                                                        
    int x;                                                            
    int y;                                                            
    shared_ints[3] = 0;                                               

    if((pid = fork()) < 0) {                                          
        printf("Fork error \n");                                      
        exit(-1);                                                     
    } else if(pid > 0 && shared_ints[3] == 0) { // Parent code        
        // Ask user for first input                                   
        printf("Enter your first number:");                           
        scanf("%d", &x);                                              
        printf("\n");                                                 

        // Ask user for second input                                  
        printf("Enter your second number:");                          
        scanf("%d", &y);                                              
        printf("\n");                                                 

        // Assign first value to shared memory                        
        shared_ints[0] = x;                                           

        // Assign second value to shared memory                       
        shared_ints[1] = y;                                           

        // Tell child that it can compute the sum now                 
        shared_ints[3] = 1;                                           

        // Trap parent in a while-loop while the child                
        // computes the sum                                           
        while(shared_ints[3] == 1);                                   

        // Child has completed calculating the sum and                
        // the parent can print the sum                               
        if(shared_ints[3] == 2) {                                     
            printf("The sum is: %d", shared_ints[2]);                 
            printf("\n");                                             
        }                                                             
    } else { // Child code                                            
        // Wait for parent to accept input values                     
        while(shared_ints[3] == 0);                                   

        // Calculate the sum                                          
        shared_ints[2] = shared_ints[0] + shared_ints[1];             

        // Tell parent sum has been calculated                        
        shared_ints[3] = 2;                                           
    }                                                                 
}
```

The sum calculation works until I go to the fourth-iteration of the sum calculation (this is the output):

```
Created shared memory object /my_shared_memory
Shared memory segment allocated correctly (16 bytes).
Enter your first number:1
Enter your second number:2
The sum is: 3
Enter your first number:Enter your first number:3
Enter your second number:4
The sum is: 7
Enter your first number:Enter your first number:5
Enter your second number:6
The sum is: 11
Enter your first number:Enter your first number:7
Enter your second number:8
Enter your second number:9
Enter your second number:
```

An interesting bug I see is that after I print the sum, the program asks for the first input twice as suggested here: `Enter your first number:Enter your first number:3`, and then in the fourth sum iteration, it asks for the second number several times before calculating the sum.

Comment: what is `shared_seg_size`?

Comment: `int shared_seg_size = (4 * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that you're forking on each iteration of the outer `while` loop, so the first time around, you have one child, then you have a child that thinks it has grown up and is a parent (as well as the parent that knows it is a parent).  And it gets worse as you continue.

Another problem is that you're allocating shared memory on each iteration of the outer `while` loop.  I'm not sure it's exactly a memory leak, but it probably isn't a good idea.

To fix:

- Move the `mmap()` and the `fork()` outside the `while (1)` loop.
- The parent process will have a loop — in its own function, not all inside `main()`, please — that reads from the user, transfers to the child, reads the result from the child, and continues.
- The child process will have a loop — also in its own function, please — that reads from the parent, calculates, and continues.
- Make sure the child knows how to exit when the parent exits.
- Ideally, use a synchronization mechanism other than busy waiting.  A couple of mutexes or a couple of semaphores would be good.  The processes would wait to be told there's work for them to do, rather than spinning their wheels (very fast) while waiting for the next task.

---

#### More or less working code

This uses a header `"stderr.h"` and functions `err_setarg0()` and `err_syserr()` from code I wrote because error reporting is crucial and these make it easy.  You should be able to find code on SO from me with working versions of that header and those functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static void be_childish(int *shared_ints);
static void be_parental(int *shared_ints);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *file = "fidget";
    int shared_seg_size = 4 * sizeof(int);

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc > 1)
        file = argv[1];

    int fd = open(file, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600);
    if (fd < 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to open file %s for read/write\n", file);
    /* Assume sizeof(int) == 4 */
    if (write(fd, "abcdefghijklmnop", shared_seg_size) != shared_seg_size)
        err_syserr("Failed to write %d bytes to %s\n", shared_seg_size, file);
    int *shared_ints = mmap(NULL, shared_seg_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (shared_ints == 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to mmap file %s\n", file);

    shared_ints[3] = 0;

    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        err_syserr("Failed to fork\n");
    else if (pid  == 0)
        be_childish(shared_ints);
    else
        be_parental(shared_ints);
    return 0;
}

static void be_childish(int *shared_ints)
{
    while (1)
    {
        // Wait for parent to generate input values
        while (shared_ints[3] == 0 || shared_ints[3] == 2)
        {
            printf("Child: %d\n", shared_ints[3]);
            usleep(500000);
        }

        if (shared_ints[3] != 1)
        {
            printf("Child: exiting\n");
            return;
        }

        // Calculate the sum
        shared_ints[2] = shared_ints[0] + shared_ints[1];

        printf("Child: calculated %d + %d = %d\n", shared_ints[0], shared_ints[1], shared_ints[2]);

        // Tell parent sum has been calculated
        shared_ints[3] = 2;
    }
}

static void be_parental(int *shared_ints)
{
    while (1)
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        // Ask user for first input
        printf("Enter your first number:");
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
        {
            printf("Parent: exiting\n");
            shared_ints[3] = -1;    /* Tell child to exit */
            return;
        }
        printf("\n");

        // Ask user for second input
        printf("Enter your second number:");
        if (scanf("%d", &y) != 1)
        {
            printf("Parent: exiting\n");
            shared_ints[3] = -1;    /* Tell child to exit */
            return;
        }
        printf("\n");

        // Assign first value to shared memory
        shared_ints[0] = x;

        // Assign second value to shared memory
        shared_ints[1] = y;

        // Tell child that it can compute the sum now
        shared_ints[3] = 1;

        // Trap parent in a while-loop while the child
        // computes the sum
        while (shared_ints[3] == 1)
        {
            printf("Parent: %d\n", shared_ints[3]);
            usleep(500000);
        }

        // Child has completed calculating the sum and
        // the parent can print the sum
        if (shared_ints[3] == 2)
        {
            printf("The sum is: %d", shared_ints[2]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Parent: unexpected control %d - exiting\n", shared_ints[2]);
            shared_ints[3] = -1;    /* Tell child to exit */
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This code has debugging in the busy-wait loops, and a delay of 0.5 seconds on each read cycle.  You can tweak that to suit yourself, and lose the output once your sure it's working for you, too.  Note that the code destroys a file `fidget` unless you specify an alternative name to be created/destroyed.  It does not remove the file as it exits; it probably should.

#### Sample run

```
$ ./dualproc
Enter your first number:Child: 0
1

Enter your second number:Child: 0
2

Parent: 1
Child: calculated 1 + 2 = 3
Child: 2
The sum is: 3
Enter your first number:Child: 2
Child: 2
3

Enter your second number:Child: 2
4

Parent: 1
Child: calculated 3 + 4 = 7
Child: 2
The sum is: 7
Enter your first number:Child: 2
q
Parent: exiting
$ Child: exiting

$
```

The parent exited before the child did; no big surprise there.  You could upgrade the code to use `wait()` to wait for the child to exit if you preferred.

Comment: Apologies for my utter ignorance to C - you are right. How should I change my code so it keeps calculating sums but at the same time not forking during each iteration?

Comment: Thanks for this terrific answer, Jonathan. For "Make sure the child knows how to exit when the parent exits", what I can do is, when I detect a Ctrl+C, I will kill the child when the parent exists - what do you think?

Comment: You don't need to worry about signals; the signals that terminate the parent will terminate the child too.  However, you should be detecting EOF (or other formatting problems on the input) and stopping.  You could set `shared_ints[3] = -1;` (or 4, or any other currently unused value) in the parent, and also arrange for the child to check that the non-zero value it reads is 1 or 2, exiting if it is neither.

Comment: The assignment instruction also calls for the following "When the Control+C signal is received from the keyboard, your program must behave as follows. The child should ignore the signal and must not terminate. The parent, on the other hand, must handle this signal by first detaching and removing the shared memory segment, terminating
its child via the SIGKILL signal, and finally terminating itself." That is mainly why I am asking that question.

Comment: OK; then you need to do what it says. Note that `mmap()`'d memory isn't the same as a shared memory segment obtained via the `shmget()` et al functions. Exiting a program deals with `mmap()`'d memory; shared memory doesn't vanish so readily. Of course, killing a child via SIGKILL is not recommended. It's too brutal — it doesn't leave the child an opportunity to protest the infanticide being performed on it. So, as I said before: do as you're requested to do. Set up the differential signal handling, even though it really isn't necessary. And do look at whether you should be using `shmat()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: There is a problem here in a corner case where the parent quits and the child is still waiting for the parents input value - can happen if the user breaks the program when shared_ints[3] != 0

To demonstrate @Jonathan Leffler's excellent answer, here's my suggestion for a fix:

```
    /* These are better declared outside the while loop */
    // Declare a shared memory integer array                          
    int *shared_ints = mmap(NULL, shared_seg_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);                                                                        
    int x;                                                            
    int y;                                                            

// Fork the process                                                   
while(1) {                                                            

    shared_ints[3] = 0; 
    if((pid = fork()) < 0) {                                          
        printf("Fork error \n");                                      
        exit(-1);                                                     
    } else if(pid > 0 && shared_ints[3] == 0) { // Parent code        
        // Ask user for first input                                   
        printf("Enter your first number:");                           
        scanf("%d", &x);                                              
        printf("\n");                                                 

        // Ask user for second input                                  
        printf("Enter your second number:");                          
        scanf("%d", &y);                                              
        printf("\n");                                                 

        // Assign first value to shared memory                        
        shared_ints[0] = x;                                           

        // Assign second value to shared memory                       
        shared_ints[1] = y;                                           

        // Tell child that it can compute the sum now                 
        shared_ints[3] = 1;                                           

        // Trap parent in a while-loop while the child                
        // computes the sum                                           
        while(shared_ints[3] == 1);                                   

        // Child has completed calculating the sum and                
        // the parent can print the sum                               
        if(shared_ints[3] == 2) {                                     
            printf("The sum is: %d", shared_ints[2]);                 
            printf("\n");                                             
        }                                                             
    } else { // Child code                                            
        // Wait for parent to accept input values                     
        while(shared_ints[3] == 0);                                   

        // Calculate the sum                                          
        shared_ints[2] = shared_ints[0] + shared_ints[1];             

        // Tell parent sum has been calculated                        
        shared_ints[3] = 2;   
        /* Child process should finish, so it doesn't fork
           and in the upper while loop. this is a fast way to do it */
        exit(0);                            
    }                                                                 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you did differently in this other than adding `exit(0)` within the child?

Comment: That was the main problem - adding exit will prevent the child from forking over and over. Other than that I just moved initializations outside the while loop

Comment: Ah I see. Let me give it a try.

Comment: The `exit()` probably _does_ stop the children accumulating, but it also probably isn't really what you needed.  Since the `fork()` is still inside the outer `while` loop, it certainly isn't a direct translation of what I had in mind.  I was expecting `fork()` to be executed once only: `if (fork() == 0) { be_childish(shared_ints); } else { be_parental(shared_ints); }`.  Each of those functions would have its own loop — the childish one simply reading and writing to shared memory, and the parental one both reading from the user and writing to and reading from shared memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffer right, that would be a lot tidier. I tried to stick as close as I could to the original code.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I think you should accept Jonathan's answer

Comment: @IshayPeled If I take the variable and shared memory declarations outside the loop, the program terminates on the first sum calculation. However, if I keep it in the while loop, Jonathan says that there may be memory leaks. How should I approach this?

Comment: From the looks of it, there shouldn't be any memory leaks in this code. Perhaps there is more code surrounding it?

Comment: Nope, this is everything. I was just assuming since I have the shared memory declaration within the while, it would cause memory leaks. I couldn't bring it outside the while loop since the program terminates.

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration of the big while loop, the parent and child process are calling `fork()` in this line:

```
if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
```

You are repeatedly spawning more child processes after every iteration and can be creating unexpected interactions.

Comment: I added an `exit(0)` within the child node to prevent this from happening.